# CFile returns debug assertion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, migrate, cfile

I have an old project in Visual C++ and I'm trying to migrate it to Visual Studio 2013. When I verify if a txt file exists, `CFile` returns debug assertion error. The code is:

```
if (!txt_file.Open(txt_name,    CFile::modeWrite | CFile::shareDenyWrite  | CFile::typeText))
{
    //action if the file exists
}
```

What is the problem, I'm doing something wrong ?
Thank you

L.E. :

`txt_file` is declared as : `CStdioFile txt_file` in the class `trace` 
`txt_name` is declared as : `private CString txt_name` in the method named `open_file` from class `trace`  
The method `open_file` contains the if statement that returns debug assertion error.

Comment: You should be able to step through the code and determine the cause of the assertion.

Comment: I'm using my crystal ball here, but if it's an older application, it was probably written for an older version of Windows where the security restrictions were not as strictly enforced. Where is this file located? Is it in the root directory of the disk or in a subdirectory of a common directory (like Program Files), where you (as a normal user) would not be able to open it for writing? If so, you need to move the file some place else more appropriate for a normal user to have read/write access, like the My Documents folder.

Comment: It would help a lot of you would say what the assertion error is. That said, in my experience, Visual C++ makes the curious assertion that the creation date of any file you try to open is later than 00:00 1/1/1970. Some file import sources leave a zero in the creation date field, which results in that particular assertion failure. I have never understood why that assertion is there.

Comment: @CodyGray The txt file is in `D:\my_project\sub-folder`

Comment: @Logicrat The assertion is : `Debug Assertion Failed! File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\filecore.cpp line 179 `  P.S.: I don't have that path locally in my machine. The actual path of that file is `C:\ ..`

Comment: @Madalin This isn't the full assertion failure message, and the part you pasted is missing the reason for assertion.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I've pasted the whole message that appears in the window. I don't see in the message window the reason for assertion.

Comment: @Madalin I find that hard to believe, since all asserts that I saw, contained the actual expression that caused the assertion.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I've checked again. This is the whole message: `Debug Assertion Failed! File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\filecore.cpp
Line: 179 For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)`

Comment: So you press "Retry", which drops you into the MFC source code. Then you look at the Call Stack window and trace back to the top most code file in the list that is part of *your* application. This will tell you which line of code caused the error.

Comment: @CodyGray The code that caused the error is the `if` statement from the current question. I've done what you said and in the call stack is the same line.

Comment: @Madalin And, what was the condition, _in MFC code_ that caused the assertion?

Comment: `// shouldn't open an already open file (it will leak) ASSERT(m_hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);`

Comment: If it's saying that the file is already open, do you run that code more than once? If so, do you close the file if it succeeds?

Comment: That piece of code is running only once. I've tried the solution posted by Danny below and now the debug assertion error is triggered at : `txt_file.Close();`

Comment: Your code looks wrong, or the comment looks wrong. If `CFile::Open` fails, it returns zero. But your comment says "action if the file exists" - that's the wrong way round.

Comment: That's the wrong way to check for file existence. See [Superstition: Why is GetFileAttributes the way old-timers test file existence?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071023-00/?p=24713)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using:

```
CFile txt_file;
```

`CFile` does not support text mode.

To open in text mode, you can change to:

```
CStdioFile txt_file;
```

That should fix the problem (at least, using `CFile` in this case generates an assertion).

---

If you are using `CStdioFile` already, there's probably a problem with the (combination of) open modes. As a test, try to remove `CFile::shareDenyWrite`. There could be security restrictions too.

> mfc\filecore.cpp Line: 179

It might be best to step through it with the debugger, or have a look at `filecore.cpp Line: 179` to see what gets checked there (I would look it up for you, but don't have Visual Studio 2013 at hand right now - probably open modes).

**Update**:

> This is line 179:
>
> `// shouldn't open an already open file (it will leak)`
>
> `ASSERT(m_hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);`

The file is already opened. So no need to open it again, or first needs to be closed, to open with other open modes.

```
txt_file.Close();
```

Or to test if the file is open (not valid for `CMemFile`):

```
if (txt_file.m_hFile != CFile::hFileNull) { // file already open
    txt_file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Actually, txt_file is declared as : `CString txt_file` and it contains the path to the txt file.

Comment: @Madalin - That would be `txt_name` ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very tired... So : `CString txt_name` and `CStdioFile txt_file`. This is how they are declared now. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: This is line 179 : `// shouldn't open an already open file (it will leak)
 ASSERT(m_hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);` I've removed `CFile::shareDenyWrite` and I have the same issue.

Comment: Thank you for the solution Danny. I've added the `if` statement and now the debug assertion error is triggered at this new line ( where I check if the file is open ). Exactly at : `txt_file.Close();`

Comment: @Madalin - Strange, tested this here. Try `if (txt_file.m_hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {` instead - but this is actually the same. But it would be better to close the file where it needs to be closed, or not reopen it at all.

Comment: Danny, I've modified the `if` statement. I have the same issue. At : `txt_file.Close()` the debug assertion error appears. LE : I've noticed now that if I press continue in the error window the file is created ( if it doesn't exist ). So the code it's working, but why the error ?

Comment: @Madalin - Very strange, but you'll have to step through it with the debugger to see what's happening. Do you mean you had an assertion with `Open()` even if the file didn't exist yet? Is the file used elsewhere in the program? Is there a memory mapping created over the file?

Comment: No, there is no memory mapping over the file. Yes, the file is used elsewhere in the program ( after it is created or succesfully opened ).

Comment: @Madalin - I mean, is the file used before you try to open it here? And where do you get the assertion if you step through it with the debugger? To make sure: you first check the file handle, if not `CFile::hFileNull` you try to close it, and that asserts?

Comment: No, the file is not used anywhere. If I step through it with the debugger I get the assertion when I call `txt_file.Close()`. And if I remove `txt_file.Close()` I get the assertion just after the if statement from the question.

Comment: @Madalin - Ok, but where is the assertion triggered in filecore.cpp/filetxt.cpp? That's where the information, and possible solution is.

Comment: Yes, in filecore.cpp/filetxt.cpp it's triggered. At the following line ( 380 )  : `ASSERT_VALID(this);
 ASSERT(m_pStream != NULL);`

Comment: @Madalin sound like memory corruption due to another problem somewhere else in your code. Please show how `txt_file` is declared; is it an class/struct member member, is it a local variable, a global variable.. Please show also more relevant code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thank you for your comment ! I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !

Instead of using the piece of code from the question to check if the file exists, I've used the following code :

```
  CFileStatus sts; //status flag
        bool chkifFileExists = CFile::GetStatus(txt_name, sts); // return TRUE if the file exists else return false




        if (!(chkifFileExists))

{
 //do something
}
```

Thank you all for your support  !